# Grounding rod conflicts with circuit tester

Tags: wiring, grounding, shed, solar

I built an off-grid shed with solar system. The output from the solar panels goes to a charge controller, then to a 12V LiPO4 battery. I convert the 12V from the battery to 120V ac using a 1500W inverter. When I plug in a 120V circuit tester (the item with LED lights indicating circuit status available you can buy everywhere) to the inverter output, it indicates an “open ground” situation. I then installed a grounding rod outside the shed and connected it to the ground wires on the frames of the charge controller and inverter. I still get an open ground reading from the plug-in circuit tester. I know that ground rods appear controversial in solar circles, and some say you don’t need them, but the inverter directions require a real ground. I am too far from a building with a ground circuit. What am I missing in this? I am a newbie to solar, but I am a scientist who has taken E&M in physics. But theory is not real world circuitry and application.

Comment: What's the resistance between your ground rod and the ground on your outlets? If it's basically zero, I think you can ignore the fish finder results, as it's probably being fooled by the weirdness of this setup.

Comment: Your tester is looking at the "Equipment Grounding Conductor" (EGC/third prong on the outlet), while a grounding rod is part of the "Grounding Electrode System". These are related, but not the same thing. The EGC exists to provide a fault conductor back to the circuit breaker panel so there is a complete fault circuit in case the hot conductor touches something it shouldn't, thus tripping the breaker and shutting off power to the hot conductor.

Comment: What's the resistance (check while it's **shut down**) between the ground pin on the inverter output (or outlets connected to the inverter output) and the neutral blade on the plug? What's the resistance between each of those and the point you attached the ground rod to? What make/model of inverter? This is probably a local wiring error, but with no details/diagrams/pictures of the wiring it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 6):

The symptoms are indicative of not having a neutral/ground bond in place, (or not having a ground wire connected in the receptacle, to be complete) but at the present level of detail it's hard to know where that should be done, as we have only the vaguest description of the inverter.

If the inverter is feeding an electrical service panel, the bond most likely should be in there.

If the inverter has only a couple of NEMA 5-15 outlets and no provision for connecting to a panel, the bond probably should be internal to it, but likely can be configured to be disconnected for situations where that would be inappropriate, such as plugging it into an inlet to feed a panel.

That should be covered in the manual, assuming it's something reputable, rather than gawd-knows-what direct imported by you (even if the website you bought it from concealed that detail from you.)

A US-style 240/120 VAC or 120VAC-only system should have a neutral-ground bond at one, and only one, and exactly one place. Not Zero, not Two or more.

When you are fully-off-grid, your inverter is the primary 120VAC power source and the bond should be either in it, or in the first panel (main panel) after it. When you are on-grid, the neutral-ground bond is located in the panel (main panel) that has the service disconnect breaker in it. All other panels are sub-panels, with neutral and ground isolated from each other.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that ground rods appear controversial in solar circles, and some say you don’t need them

Are those people licensed electricians? Do they sit on any NEC code writing panels?

I didn't think so.

In the early days of electricity, they wired houses with hot(s) and neutral wires, fullstop.  You may recall seeing ancient 120V sockets with 2 slots.  *Obviously, that did not go well, which is why in 1954 they started legislating in the concept of grounding. Grounding was universal by 1965*.

> I built an off-grid shed with solar system. T I convert the 12V from the battery to 120V ac using a 1500W inverter.

That's not a problem. That's what is called a **separately derived service**.  I have two of those myself.

You simply take the hot(s) and neutral from the inverter, same as you would with the 3-wire service from a utility.  Bring that into a main service panel such as a HOM612L100 family, and it is a **main panel** in the full NEC sense.  Wire the main panel normally, including neutral-ground bond and ground rods tied to ground.  Grounds can be guests on the neutral bar.

If the source is inherently current-limited below 20A, I don't see where a main breaker would be necessary.

> When I plug in a 120V circuit tester (the item with LED lights indicating circuit status available you can buy everywhere) to the inverter output, it indicates an “open ground” situation.

Because it was not wired according to the National Electrical Code, or to be more precise, the 1954 National Electrical Code.

Bring this up to at least NEC 2011 and see if the problem persists.

> I then installed a grounding rod outside the shed and connected it to the ground wires on the frames of the charge controller and inverter. I still get an open ground reading from the plug-in circuit tester.

While that is correct, I suspect you're short of NEC 2011, and have failed to supply the required neutral-ground bond.  Your main panel will take care of this if you place the grounds as guests on the neutral bar.  Note grounds can fill the neutral bar up to 3 per space depending on panel labeling.  Neutrals must be solo.

> But theory is not real world circuitry and application.

NEC squashes all the theory out of electrical installations, so you don't need an engineer to wire a house.   Trouble is, an actual engineer can be a "bull in the china shop" by trying to re-invent every rule in the book.

Answer (score -1):

The most important function of ground is what is called PE - protective earth.

The idea is that *everything* you can touch is tied to the same potential: metal exteriors on a machine is connected to ground via the grounding prong in the socket. The conductive kitchen sink is connected to ground, and so forth. The net result is that if a fault occurs, so that a live wire touches the metal chassis, or something becomes wet and conducts electricity to chassis, the current will pass through the ground wire, and not you when you touch the kitchen sink and faulty machine at the same time.

An added benefit is that we can use GFCI's to detect faults. They basically sum currents in the two wires of a circuit, and if the sum is non-zero they trip. They can trip at low values (mA-tens of mA), thus provide great protection.

The ground point is tied with N at the distribution transformer, and depending on the grid type, also tied at the intake to the building. The literal earth rod is there to ensure that the (conductive) ground and other surfaces are at the same potential as the ground conductor.

In a solar setup you don't have any electrical company providing a ground reference. You will have to set it up yourself, and how to do this depends on code. It may be to tie it together with N at the panel.

Your ground tester probably verifies that PE and N is reasonably close in voltage (or impedance).

Comment: Grounding and bonding has nothing to do with the functioning of GFCIs. The provide exactly the same protection without it.

Comment: @nobody The GFCI needs a separate path for them to work. They sum current in the wires, and if the sum is non-zero they trip. Without a separate path to earth that's not possible.

Comment: Then why does the NEC allow for and _encourage_ the installation of a GFCI on a two-wire circuit (hot/neutral) with the requirement of a "no equipment ground" label if the GFCI won't work without a ground?

Comment: @FreeMan Because the alternate path *is* there. It's trough the environment, so that the sum in the two wires can be non-zero. If you have a *isolated* setup with *no* connection except the two wires, the current ***can't*** be non-zero. Consider for instance a light bulb connected to a battery; the current on the poles of the battery *have* to be equal and opposite.

Comment: @vidarlo GFCIs do not require any ground wires to operate. They will power up and provide protection without any ground wire or ground bond upstream. There are plenty of possible faults that don’t involve “ground”, like protected hot back to unprotected neutral. And remember, if there isn’t a completed circuit flowing current,  there *is* no fault to interrupt.

Comment: @nobody In an isolated setup GFCI's can't operate. They make sense in a system with ground. If the installation is entirely isolated they don't make sense.